# dereferencing std::shared_ptr<T[]>?

Tags: c++, stl

In bellow function I need to dereference shared pointer to an array of `TCHAR`
however none of the operands available in `std::share_ptr` seem to work:

The `FormatMessage` API expects `PTSTR` which is in case of `UNICODE` `wchar_t*`
How to dereference the given pointer (see comment in the code)?

If you think the same thing could be achieved with more elegant sintax that it would be great you provide example code.

```
const std::shared_ptr<TCHAR[]> FormatErrorMessage(const DWORD& error_code)
{
    constexpr short buffer_size = 512;
    std::shared_ptr<TCHAR[]> message = std::make_shared<TCHAR[]>(buffer_size);

    const DWORD dwChars = FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        nullptr,
        error_code,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
        *message,   // no operator "*" matches these operands
        buffer_size,
        nullptr);

    return message;
}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to answers and commnts (the only) way to make it work with Microsoft compiler is this:

```
const std::shared_ptr<std::array<WCHAR, buffer_size>>
    FormatErrorMessageW(const DWORD& error_code, DWORD& dwChars)
{
    const std::shared_ptr<std::array<WCHAR, buffer_size>> message =
        std::make_shared<std::array<WCHAR, buffer_size>>();

    dwChars = FormatMessageW(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        nullptr,    // The location of the message definition.
        error_code,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
        message.get()->data(),
        buffer_size,
        nullptr);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Notice that `make_shared<T[]>(std::size_t)` is only available since C++20.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using `shared_ptr` at all and not using `std::wstring` (or `std::basic_string<TCHAR>`) instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I want to avoid copying the string when function returns, do you think I gained no performance benefit? or maybe I could just use plain heap pointer for best results.

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to add that msvc seems to support this only partially, ie. it does not work with non scalar types. I'll rewrite code to use `std::array<TCHAR>` instead of `TCHAR[]`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for input, I've updated my post according to your suggestion and this is how I made it work with current msvc.

Comment: @metablaster "*I want to avoid copying the string when function returns*" - things like move semantics and copy elision will address that for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*message` returns `TCHAR&`, whereas `FormatMessage` requires `TCHAR*` there. Instead of `*message` do `message.get()`.

Also, since this function doesn't keep a reference to the formatted message, it should return `std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]>` to document the fact that the caller is now the sole owner.

Comment: I don't understand, does that mean the `message` variable will not be initialized if there is no reference'

Comment: @metablaster `*message` returns `TCHAR&`, whereas you need `TCHAR*`.

Comment: awesome, learning something new. tnx. intellisense doesn't seem to give member get() so I didn't see it do you know why?

Comment: @metablaster I use `emacs` with `rtags` and it works perfectly.

Comment: `&*message` is not strictly conforming, because `std::shared_ptr<T[]>::operator*` is not required to have a well-formed definition. `message.get()` is the right thing to do.