# Is const_cast<char*>(const char*) undefined behavior in case of std::string::data()?

Tags: c++, string

I have `std::string&` argument in function and need to access it's storage and modify it with new string.

I don't know in general (not just std::string data) if `const_cast` against `const char*` will result in undefined behavior?

for example it looks like this:

```
// method 1
void foo(std::string& ref_param)
{
      const_cast<char*>(ref_param.data()) = "this is new string";
}

// method 2
void bar(std::string param)
{
     foo(param);
}

int main()
{
      bar("initial string");
      return 0;
}
```

I cant just assign string with new value because calling function accepts `char` array not string.

Comment: You are working from some bad thinking here. `data` returns a pointer, but it is a copy of the pointer held by the string. Assigning to this copy doesn't do anything long-term.

Comment: You can use `[0]` if it's not `const`.

Comment: And if somehow it did, you would be replacing a pointer to a dynamically allocated buffer owned by the `string` with a pointer to a string literal. This would leak the `string`'s original buffer and when the `string` tried to modify or `delete` this string literal there would be fireworks.

Comment: Ok, thank you for response, that's what I thought but couldn't find an answer. is it possible to create string with `char*` array instead of default const char? and then acces it's storage?

Comment: what is the actual problem? "I cant just assign string with new value because calling function accepts char array not string." what function?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-formatmessage

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do and why. Too many misconceptions getting in the way when you try to explain in terms of the solution that doesn't work.

Comment: if `ref_param = "this is new string"` didn't work I'd be horrified. BUT... `void bar(std::string param)` is pass by value, so once again it would be modifying a copy. Take advantage of `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` to get a suitable buffer. Copy that buffer into the `string`. Make sure that A) you free this buffer after copying into the `string` and B) `FormatMessage` is not returning a unicode string. Copying unicode into a regular `string` gets messy.

Comment: @user4581301 I see your point thank you!, I'm already using a different more modern way to allocate buffer and also avoid copying strings!, if you wan't to know see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238987/dereferencing-stdshared-ptrt as for UNICODE vs ANSI I'm already using fn overloads, in this question I wanted to make use of last parameter in `FormatMessage API` but it's not possible if formatting error codes, I misread the documentation.